# Covering by measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on the following problem from real analysis. Let $A_1,A_2,\dots, A_{10}$ be Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$. Assume that almost every $x \in [0,1]$ belongs to nine of these sets. Show that there exists $k \in \{1,2,\dots,10\}$ such that $m(A_k) \geqslant \frac{9}{10}$.

Here's my approach. By way of contradiction, assume that $m(A_k) < \frac{9}{10}$ for $k = 1,2,\dots,10$. Let $B$ denote the set that satiesfies $m(B) = 1$ and every $x \in B$ belongs to  nine subsets. We can consider the the union of all possible intersections of nine subsets, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
C = \bigcup_{(i_1,\dots,i_9)}\bigcap_{n=1}^{9} A_{i_n}
\end{equation*}
it follows that $B \subseteq C$ and hence
\begin{align*}
m(B) \leqslant m(C) &\leqslant \sum_{(i_1,\dots,i_9)} m(\bigcap_{n=1}^{9} A_{i_n})\\
&< \sum_{(i_1,\dots,i_9)} \frac{9}{10}\\
& = 10 \cdot \frac{9}{10} = 9
\end{align*}
The last equality follows from the fact that there are 10 ways to choose 9 distinct indices.

However, this is not good enough for a contradiction. Is there an alternative way to attack this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hypothesis, $\sum_{k=1}^{10} 1_{A_k}(x)\ge 9$ for a.e. $x\in[0,1]$. Integrate:
$$
{1\over 10}\sum_{k=1}^{10}m(A_k)\ge {9\over 10}.
$$
If the average of a collection of 10 numbers is at least a certain number $b$ (in this case $b=9/10$) what can you say about that collection of numbers?